# Extend syntax match region

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

The Javascript syntax file for Vim defines region for one line comments

```
syn match   javaScriptLineComment      "\/\/.*" contains=@Spell,javaScriptCommentTodo
```

The rule `javaScriptCommentTodo` highlights certain keywords, but I want to highlight other keywords with a different color:

```
syn keyword jsCommentMark FEATURE SOURCE NOTE 
hi jsCommentMark ctermfg=130 guifg=#af5f00 "rgb=175,95,0
```

As a quick fix I redefine the original rule in my after syntax file:

```
syn match   javaScriptLineComment      "\/\/.*" contains=@Spell,javaScriptCommentTodo,jsCommentMark
```

Is there a cleaner way to extend the "contains" value of an already defined rule?

Comment: Your quick fix line is identical to the original; I think you've missed appending `,jsCommentMark`.

Comment: Another remark: By convention, syntax group names start with the filetype. So, instead of `jsCommentMark`, you should use `javascriptCommentMark` (as long as that isn't yet used in the original syntax). Dunno why the original script has the `javaScript` capitalization; this isn't right, neither...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, *syntax clusters* are a built-in abstraction that would enable this. For a demonstration, have a look at `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/sh.vim`:

```
syn cluster shCommentGroup  contains=shTodo,@Spell
syn keyword shTodo  contained       COMBAK FIXME TODO XXX
syn match   shComment       "^\s*\zs#.*$"   contains=@shCommentGroup
```

Here, the `shComment` contains a syntax cluster (`@shCommentGroup`), whose only default member is `shTodo`.

With this in place, you can add additional syntax groups (e.g. in `~/.vim/after/syntax/sh.vim`), like this:

```
syn match shMyGroup ...
hi shMyGroup ...
syn cluster shCommentGroup add=shMyGroup
```

Since this is an advanced concept, most syntax files do not use this mechanism. If you feel strongly about the maintainability and purity, you could contact the author of the Javascript syntax, and suggest / submit an enhancement. IMO your current workaround is fine as well.